# JobHostConfiguration Queues.BatchSize effect on EventHubTrigger

Tags: c#, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I am currently trying to optimize some *inherited* batch processing code in a webjob. My concern is the `config.Queues.BatchSize = 5;` line. I am not an Azure expert so I have done a decent amount of reading about this before asking. My conclusion is the following: `config.Queues.BatchSize` is used for configuring Queues, as shown [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Queues), which means it should not affect the webjob at all. You can see the initialization code below:

```
static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Started...");
        JobHostConfiguration config = new JobHostConfiguration()
        {
            NameResolver = new EventHubNameResolver(),
        };
        var options = EventProcessorOptions.DefaultOptions;

        options.MaxBatchSize = 5;

        var eventHubConfig = new EventHubConfiguration(options);
        string eventHubName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EventHubName"];

        eventHubConfig.AddReceiver(eventHubName, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EventHubConnectionString"]);

        config.UseEventHub(eventHubConfig);

        config.Queues.BatchSize = 5;
        JobHost host = new JobHost(config);
        host.RunAndBlock();
    }
```

The function that is actually getting called when new items arrive in the EventHub is:

```
public static async Task ProcessData([EventHubTrigger("%EventHubName%")] string eventDataSet, TextWriter log)
    {
        ...
    }
```

My first observation is that the first parameter in the called function should be of type `EventData[]`, not `string` (which I have changed in my local code). However, while monitoring the console output I am struggling to fully understand if the queue configuration is actually affecting the webjob.

Should I expect `config.Queues.BatchSize = 5;` to alter the way in which this webjob's processing function is called?